# How can I set the ReturnUrl when I am using RedirectToAction?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a controller that redirects to another action, e.g.

`mysite.com/food/3`

This action does a `RedirectToAction` to an action called `Cake` and passes in id=3.

If the user is not authenticated at that point, you go back to the loginpage, but the RedirectUrl is `/Cake` (without any mention of the id) and not `/food/3`. This causes an error once you log in because firstly it shouldn't be accessed via that url in the browser, and secondly because the parameters have vanished.

Is there a simple way to make sure it redirects to the original URL in the browser, or do I have to write a custom authorize attribute and store a lookup table to get the parent page?

Comment: Is the `RedirectToAction` really necessary? Can you just route to the action you really want instead of jumping through hoops? Keep in mind, `RedirectToAction` will do an extra round trip by sending a 302 response to the browser, which causes it to send another request to your application before it finally responds.

Answer (score 0):

Gonna take a stab at this one.
`Food` and `Cake` take `id` values and redirect parameters and just pass them around freely where they can be used as you see fit.

**Food**

```
public ActionResult Food (int id, string returnUrl = string.Empty)
{
   // Do work
   return RedirectionToAction("Cake", new { id, returnUrl })
}
```

**Cake**

```
[Authorize]
Cake (int id, string returnUrl = string.Empty)
{
   // Do work
   if (returnUrl != string.Empty) 
     return Redirect (returnUrl);
   return View();
}
```

A problem arises when a View is finally returned to the client because then you have to somehow get that `returnUrl` into the form posted when they submit their login info because you want to use it later.  So the first step is getting it into the View's form so it's included in the model that gets posted.  One way to do that is the `ViewBag`; another way is pulling it from the query string.  I've shown an example of both below.

#### Option 1:

**Login**

```
Login (string returnUrl = string.Empty)
{
   ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
   return View();
}
```

**Login.cshtml**

```
Model.ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl;
```

#### Option 2:

**Login**

```
Login ()
{
   return View();
}
```

**Login.cshtml**

```
Model.ReturnUrl = Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"];
```

If this doesn't suffice, comment and I can try to modify this answer further.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to make this work is to put the `AuthorizeAttribute` onto the action method that calls `RedirectToAction` to short circuit the nonsense of building the wrong URL. The `FormsAuthenticationModule` uses the `RawUrl` of the request when it adds the `ReturnUrl` parameter, so it not possible to modify without building your own custom  `FormsAuthenticationModule` (which you could consider option B). But if you check authorization ***before*** you redirect the `RawUrl` will be correct.

```
// This ensures it builds the correct ReturnUrl.
[Authorize]
public ActionResult Food (int id)
{
   // Do work
   return RedirectionToAction("Cake", new { id = id })
}

// This ensures the final destination cannot be accessed
// without authorization.
[Authorize]
public ActionResult Cake (int id)
{
    // Do work
    return View();
}
```